# Site Some pages redirecting to Https Magento 2

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento2, virtualhost

I have setup virtual Host in my local system and my home page is working fine  but if I try to add any product into cart, it throws me error Unable to connect and redirect to https.

I dont know where I am going wrong.

My Virtual Host file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin magento2@test.com
    ServerName local.test.com
    ServerAlias www.local.test.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    <Directory /var/www/html/test>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

In My magento setting in `core_config_data`  I tried and set base urls properly, 
Is there anything I am missing or needs to be removed to move my site perfectly?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure Unsecured and Secured Base Urls for your site. Look here: https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/stores/store-urls.html

On the Admin sidebar, go to `Stores > Settings > Configuration > General > Web`

Set your urls in `Base URLs` tab and the same urls in `Base URLs (Secure)` tab.

Comment: hey I already did the same thing still some pages redirect to https

Comment: Ok, so if you use your `http://` urls in `Base URLs` and in `Base URLs (Secure)` then you need to flush magento cache by `bin/magento cache:flush` and restart your web server (apache/nginx).

Comment: Adding to cart, going through checkout process uses urls defined in Base URLs (Secure) section so if you still have redirects to https than it's mean that not everywhere the urls was updated (in that case in your loaded js code). It could be browser (clear browser cache, go into incognito mode, do the force refresh), could be redis, generated static cache. Clear whatever cache you can ;)